# Как выставить высоту фонового изображения к границе экрана ? Какие есть способы?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто напишите способы,а я разберусь, пробовал vh, но адаптивность тогда в 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно пытаться сделать это через `background-size`, но как видно на демо - это не вариант.

```css
body {
  height: 1000px; /* для примера выставим высоту больше, чтобы посмотреть что будет после того как проскроллим. */
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center; /* изображение по ширине будет от центра картинки, а по высоте от верха */
  background-size: auto 100vh; /* Тут самое основное, auto - это размер по ширине, он будет выстраиваться пропорционально размеру картинки. 100vh - это размер по высоте, т.е. в нашем случае 100vh равносилен 100% высоте !экрана! (вьюпорта). */
}
```

Из чего я предлагаю следующее - использовать псевдоэлемент, который будет равен ширине и высоте экрана, будет находиться вверху страницы (или в нужной высоте от границы), и картинка в нём.

Пример:

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}
 
body::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; /* Высота экрана */
  background-image: url('https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0;
  z-index: -1; /* Важно */
  pointer-events: none; /* Отключим ему таргет, на всякий пожарный.. */
}
```

**P.s.** вместо псевдоэлемента можно использовать что-нибудь другое, `<div>` например, но тогда уже придётся лезть ещё и в HTML, а данное решение только в CSS.

Comment: спасибо большое, изначально и думал реализовать псевдоэлементами

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `background-size:cover`.
Или можно попробовать `background-attachment: fixed`

Comment: `background-size: cover` растянет изображение на всю высоту и ширину `body`, `background-attachment: fixed` сделает фон "прокручиваем" вместе со скроллом. Так что не одно из ваших решений здесь неуместно.

Comment: я имею ввиду чтобы фото растягивалось и прикасалось границы нижнего экаран, не блоы той белой полосы, то что вы написали уже стоит в свойствах

Comment: картинка в background или это элемент img?